# How to declare a global variable inside a function

Tags: variables, go, scope

I am not able to find the required solution. I want to call a function and want to use some variable which is being declared in that function(I don't want to return that variable). I just want to make it global.

```
func foo(){
    temp:=30

}
func main(){
    foo()
    // How to use temp without returning or without declaring it outside foo and main
}
```

Comment: If you want to maintain a custom state, either use a struct with method pointer receivers, or use a function closure. If you're learning go, I suggest sticking with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can only declare a package variable (aka global variable) in package scope. You can *modify* it from inside a function, but you can't *declare* it inside a function. This is because anything else referring to that variable has to have that reference resolvable *at compile time*. Otherwise, what happens when `Bar()` tries to reference the variable before `Foo()` could declare it? That would break compile-time safety that Go guarantees.

That said, the solution is simple; just declare it in package scope. It's unclear in the question why you wouldn't want to do that - if you want a global, that's what you do.